# How to compare innerHTML containing a hexadeximal character reference?

Tags: javascript, hex

I have a tag containing &#x25bc ; (which is displayed as ▼ on the rendered page) :

```
<span id=up_down>&#x25bc;</span>
```

The problem is that when I try and compare innerHTML against &#x25bc ;

it is instead trying to compare ▼ == &#x25bc ; (and failing)

```
var e = document.getElementById("up_down");
if ( e.innerHTML == '&#x25b2;' )
{
  e.innerHTML = '&#x25bc;';
}
else if ( e.innerHTML == '&#x25bc;' )
{
  e.innerHTML = '&#x25b2;';
}
```

Comment: It's a poor practice to modify HTML like that. Use CSS classes instead.

Comment: I'm interested in finding out more about what you mean. Can you point me toward something I can review? Thanks!

Comment: Add/remove a class from the element depending on the state you are in. http://jsfiddle.net/JXuT4/

Comment: Thanks @katspaugh, I implemented the class switching method using background images, and learned a few things along the way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to `escape()` it and use `%u25BC` and `%u25B2` instead.

```
var e = document.getElementById("up_down");
if ( escape(e.innerHTML) == '%u25B2' )
{
  e.innerHTML = '&#x25bc;';
}
else if ( escape(e.innerHTML) == '%u25BC' )
{
  e.innerHTML = '&#x25b2;';
}​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/quQdr/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the character code instead:

```
if(e.textContent.charCodeA(0) == 0x25bc) {
  // Your code
}
```

Right now you're comparing the actual character to a string containing its HTML entity representation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var upArrow = String.fromCharCode('0x25b2');
var downArrow = String.fromCharCode('0x25bc');

if ( e.innerHTML == upArrow )
{
  e.innerHTML = downArrow;
}
else if ( e.innerHTML == downArrow )
{
  e.innerHTML = upArrow;
}
```